# Django: override default User model's error message

Tags: python, django

In my project's registration system I am using default User model:

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

How do I override default "User with this Username already exists." message with my own one? Have been searching for that for over 2 hours but I was not able to find an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is called in `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm` via the translation utility (so you can personalise the translations in the `locale/*/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` files in the same auth folder)

You can override the `error_messages['duplicate_username']` variable in your RegistrationForm, e.g.

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_messages['duplicate_username'] = 'Your message here'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But is there any way to override this message in f.ex. my forms.py file ? I guess it wouldn't be a good idea to edit core files. My registration form is very simple: `class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')`

Comment: I've added an example of code to override the message

Comment: Sorry that I am answering just now... Your code worked perfectly, thank you :) Should have thought about that. I am still a learner though.